# Start Emacs with gdb with a different main source file

Tags: window, start-up, gdb

I often run Gdb in a dedicated Emacs session. I have [code to run gdb when Emacs start and set up Many-Windows mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46637/run-gdb-from-the-command-line/46645#46645).

For one particular project, there are many programs, all written in C, that share a `main()` function but where the interesting part is in a separate source file whose base name is the same as the executable: `hello` is built from `hello.c` and `main.c`, `foo` is built from `foo.c` and `main.c`, etc. Gdb sees the `main()` function in `main.c` and therefore opens `main.c` initially, which makes perfect sense. But for this project, `main.c` is mostly irrelevant and I want to start with the program-specific source file open, e.g. `hello.c`.

I want to either instruct Gdb to consider a different file to be the “main” source, or instruct Emacs to display a different source file initially.

I wrote the code below to instruct Emacs to display a different source file. It doesn't work, and I don't understand why.

```lisp
;; Specific code for my project, where the main() function is in a boring
;; file that is shared between many executables and the interesting source
;; file is the one based on the executable name.
;; The code here is simplified from my real code and only works if all the
;; files are in the current directory.
(defvar actual-source-file (concat default-directory "/"
                                   (car command-line-args-left) ".c"))
(defun visit-actual-source ()
  (interactive)
  (gdb-display-source-buffer (find-file-noselect actual-source-file)))
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'visit-actual-source)

;; Don't ask for confirmation on exit even if a process is running.
;; This doesn't have any impact on the question, but makes testing easier.
(defun clear-buffer-process-query-on-exit-flag ()
  (let ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (if proc
        (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil))))
(defun clear-gdb-inferior-process-query-on-exit-flag ()
  (if (equal (process-name (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))) "gdb-inferior")
      (clear-buffer-process-query-on-exit-flag)))
(add-hook 'comint-exec-hook 'clear-gdb-inferior-process-query-on-exit-flag)
(defadvice gud-common-init
    (after gud-common-init-set-process-query-on-exit-flag activate)
  "Don't ask for confirmation if exiting Emacs during the debug session."
  (clear-buffer-process-query-on-exit-flag))

;; Run gdb.
(let ((command-string (combine-and-quote-strings command-line-args-left)))
  (set-frame-name (concat "gdb: " command-string))
  (gdb (concat "gdb -i=mi --args " command-string)))
(setq command-line-args-left nil)

;; Set up a nice window configuration.
(gdb-many-windows)
```

Set up a test environment:

```sh
cat <<'EOF' >main.c
void do_stuff(void);
int main() {
    do_stuff();
    return 0;
}
EOF
cat <<'EOF' >hello.c
#include <stdio.h>
void do_stuff(void) {
    puts("Hello world");
}
EOF
cc -g -o hello hello.c main.c
```

Then run Emacs with the Lisp code above in `gdb-alternate-source.el`.

```sh
emacs -q -l gdb-alternate-source.el hello
```

Desired effect: display the 6 windows of Gdb Many-Windows mode, with `hello.c` in the middle left window.
Actual effect: display the 6 windows of Gdb Many-Windows mode, with `main.c` in the middle left window. `hello.c` is open but not displayed.

If I run `M-x visit-actual-source` after Emacs starts, it has the desired effect: `hello.c` becomes displayed instead of `main.c`.

If I add `(recursive-edit)` after `(gdb-many-windows)` or before the call to `gdb-display-source-buffer` in `visit-actual-source`, then after I exit the recursive edit, `hello.c` replaces `main.c` in the middle left window and `*GNU Emacs*` (“Welcome to GNU Emacs …”) replaces `*gud-hello*` in the top left window. On the other hand, adding `(force-window-update)` or `(redisplay)` doesn't make any difference.

I guess I need to add some code to update something related to the window configuration, but what? How do I get the desired file displayed automatically when Emacs starts?